# Unit testing higher order functions in F#

Tags: unit-testing, f#, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Take the following F# example:

```
let parse mapDate mapLevel mapMessge (groups : string list) = 
    {
        DateTime = 
            mapDate(
                groups.[2] |> Int32.Parse, 
                groups.[0] |> Int32.Parse, 
                groups.[1] |> Int32.Parse)
        Level = mapLevel groups.[3]
        Message = mapMessge  groups.[4]
    }
```

I can unit test the map functions independently that's ok,  but how do I unit test that this function calls the functions passed in as arguments correctly?

In C# I would use mocks and verify the calls to them. I recently watched a pluralsight video that talked about how functional languages tend to use stubs instead of mocks. Here I could pass in a function that throws if it doesn't get the expected arguments but I'm not really sold on this approach.

I was just wondering if there were any patterns in functional programming in general for unit testing higher-order functions like this?

Comment: If `parse` returns the correct outputs for given inputs, then de facto it calls its arguments functions correctly, no?

Comment: That's true but then aren't I tightly coupling the implementation? I see what you're saying though i need to stop thinking about verifying the function is called and purely assert the output of the function given some stubs.

Comment: In fact I think checking that some functions are called in some order introduces much tighter coupling; it says 'the implementation must be like this exactly'. So I think you're getting the hang of it, starting to think in terms of pure functions and their inputs and outputs.

Comment: Is it on purpose that `mapMessge` is not used?

Comment: @RobertNielsen that's a typo I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me disagree with given answer. Actually, there is a nice way to test higher order functions without even bothering about concrete types they might take (I consider typical HOF to be totally generic, however there is no difference: approach I suggest will work with more strict HFO rightly).

Let's take something really simple, something everyone is familiar with. How about `['t] -> ['t]` function? It takes a single argument - a list of **whatever** type and returns list of the same type. Traditional OOP approach wouldn't work here: one need's to put a restriction on `'t` and test somewhat specific parameters of that type; the **only** way to make author to feel more confident with his implementation, is to increase unit tests numbers.

There is really great stuff named "category theory" in math. It's comparatively new filed of mathematics and studies things from the outside rather from than inside. In order to be able to describe things "from the outside" you need take a thing you're interested in and force it to interact with something you already know deep enough. Thus, category theory teaches to describe things **in terms of their interrelations** with other things. Can't we do the same here?..

Indeed, we can. That's actually quite easy: we got a `f : ['t] -> ['t]` already, but is there anything else such that we could make both interact and define something **common** - something that holds for each and every interaction regardless of any other factors? Let's take **any** `g: 't -> 'y`. Now we able to state: `g (List.head (f ...) = List.head (List.map g (f ...))`. I assume a certain argument of type `['t]` to substitute `...`. Please note: **given property is universal: it would hold for any pure functions composition of specified *signatures* regardless of their implementation**. Also note **how generic yet obvious** it is: there are only two distinct "objects" interacting with each other via "composition", which could also be rewritten in terms of standard F#'s `(|>), (<|)` operators.

Now the fact is that **for any** higher order (pure) function there exists such kind of universal property; mostly, there are dozens of them. Thus one able to specify their properties in terms of composition (which is regular for FP) staying at the generic level. Having such a properties in the explicit form gives one chance to autogenerate hundreds of tests, based on inputs different not only by their values (which normally done by unit tests, except the fact they are rarely autogenerated), but also by types.

Answer (score -1):

Pure functions are easier because you just have to test the outputs of your `parse` function.  You shouldn't ever need to test using side effects like you do in imperative programming.

When writing most of your unit tests, you generally use the most simple possible for your function arguments, like `identity` or similar.  Then you'd write one test named something like "mapLevel is applied to fourth group" where instead you make `mapLevel` something that's easy to recognize as changed, like `toUpper`. This lets you make sure you didn't accidentally copy/paste `mapLevel` to more than one output.  Then a similar test for `mapMessge`.